# Paginate Gallery

Tags: images, pagination, gallery

I am using the default WordPress Gallery (along with the Cleaner Gallery plugin) to display some images. The one thing that the gallery doesn't seem to have is pagination. What I'd like to do is after 6 images add Previous and Next links to navigate through the pages.

Having said that, there are several plugins that claim to add this capability, but all of them were developed without the new Media Library, that comes standard with WordPress 3.5. I don't want to change the experience for the user...I just want to possibly add functionality through functions.php or somehow on the loop itself. I have no problem applying the same thing to all galleries, so if the fix could somehow find the gallery short-code than that would be awesome! Not sure how to do it, just kind of thinking out loud here.

Any help is appreciated.

The code generated looks like this:

```
<div id='gallery-234-1' class='gallery gallery-234'>
    <div class='gallery-row gallery-clear'>
        <dl class='gallery-item col-3'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'><a href='http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-11.jpg' title='gallery-(11)'><img width="184" height="184" src="http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-11-184x184.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="gallery-(11)" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item col-3'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'><a href='http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-10.jpg' title='gallery-(10)'><img width="184" height="184" src="http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-10-184x184.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="gallery-(10)" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item col-3'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'><a href='http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-5.jpg' title='gallery-(5)'><img width="184" height="184" src="http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-5-184x184.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="gallery-(5)" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class='gallery-row gallery-clear'>
        <dl class='gallery-item col-3'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'><a href='http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-4.jpg' title='gallery-(4)'><img width="184" height="184" src="http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/gallery-4-184x184.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="gallery-(4)" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the NextGEN Gallery instead of the default gallery, there is a few extra steps, but it's not too bad.

Thanks,
Josh